# Convert sympy Interval to set notation

Tags: python, sympy

How do I convert a `solveset()` result (an `Interval`) to a string of mathematical set notation?

Consider this example

```
>>> solveset("n^2 > 4", "n", Reals)
Union(Interval.open(-oo, -2), Interval.open(2, oo))
```

Is there a method to convert this `Interval` to a string; such that:

```
>>> x = Union(Interval.open(-oo, -2), Interval.open(2, oo))
>>> f(x)
'(−∞,−2) ∪ (2,∞)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pretty` seems the to be the function your are looking for:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.pretty import pretty
var("n")
s = solveset("n^2 > 4", "n", Reals)
t = pretty(s)
print(type(t))
# <class 'str'>
print(t)
# (-∞, -2) ∪ (2, ∞)
```

Comment: Simple and exactly what I was looking for, thank you. What's the purpose of `var("n")`?

Comment: With `var("n")` I create a symbol. I was trying different things and later I forgot to remove that line of code.